# WPF Image display not updated after source is changed

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

In my MainView there is a ContentControl which is bound to a CurrentView object. The CurrentView is changed via buttons on the MainView bound to commands.

MainView

```
<Window>(...)
       <RadioButton Content="View1"
                    Command="{Binding View1Command}"/>
       <RadioButton Content="View2" 
                    Command="{Binding View2Command}"/>
   <ContentControl Content="{Binding CurrentView}"/>
</Window>
```

MainVM

(The ObservableObject class implements INotifyPropertyChanged and the RelayCommand class ICommand.)

```
class MainViewModel : ObservableObject
{
        public RelayCommand ViewCommand1 { get; set; }
        public RelayCommand ViewCommand2 { get; set; }

        public ViewModel2 VM1 { get; set; }
        public ViewModel2 VM2 { get; set; }
        
        object _currentView;
        
        public object CurrentView
        {
            get { return _currentView; }
            set 
            { 
                _currentView = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    public MainViewModel()
    {
      VM1 = new ViewModel1();
      VM1.ContentChanged += (s, e) => OnPropertyChanged();
      ViewCommand1 = new RelayCommand(o =>
            {
                CurrentView = VM1;
            });

      VM2 = new ViewModel2();
      ViewCommand2 = new RelayCommand(o =>
            {
                CurrentView = VM2;
            });
    }
 }
```

Those (sub) VM are bound to UserControls which contain image controls and a button to load the image sources from files.

View1

```
<UserControl x:Class="Project.Views.View1"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:viewModels="clr-namespace:Project.ViewModels" 
             d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=viewModels:ViewModel1}"
             mc:Ignorable="d" >
[...]
  <Button Command="{Binding LoadImagesCommand}"/>
[...]
  <Image Source="{Binding Images[0]}" "/>
  <Image Source="{Binding Images[1]}" "/>
[...]
</UserControl>
```

VM1

```
class RiJustageViewModel: ObservableObject
{
    public event EventHandler ContentChanged;
    void OnContentChanged()
    {
        ContentChanged?.Invoke(this, new EventArgs());
    }

    public RelayCommand LoadImagesCommand { get; set; }
    
    public ViewModel1()
    {
        Images = new BitmapImage[9];
        LoadImagesCommand = new RelayCommand(o => LoadImages());
    }

    BitmapImage[] _images;

    public BitmapImage[] Images
    {
        get { return _images; }
        set
        {
            _images = value;
            OnContentChanged();
        }
    }

    public void LoadImages()
    {  
        [...]
        for (int i = 0; i < files.Length; i++)
        {
           Images[i] = Utility.BmImageFromFile(files[i]);
        }
        [...]
    }
}
```

The issue now is that the images are not shown right away after they are loaded. Only after I change the content of the ContentControl to another view and then back to View1 the images are shown.

Is there a way to trigger that display right after the loading is complete without changing the content of the ContentControl?

EDIT:This should be done everytime the user wants to load new images via the button, not only during initialization.

EDIT:
With lidqy's and EldHasp's comments I was able to clean up the VM and the View using `ObservableCollection` and `ItemsControl`.

VM

```
  public class ImageItem
    {
        public string FileName{ get; set; }
        public ImageSource Image { get; set; }
        public ImageItem(string f, ImageSource im)
        {
            FileName = f;
            Image = im;
        }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<ImageItem> ImageItems { get; set; }

   [...]
   public void LoadImages()
   {
     [...]
     ImageItems.Clear();
     foreach (var file in files)
     {
        var im = Utility.BmImageFromFile(file);
        var f = Path.GetFileName(file);
        ImageItems.Add(new ImageItem(f, im));
     }
}
```

View

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ImageItems}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
      <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <UniformGrid Columns="3" Rows="3"/>
      </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
        <Grid Margin="5">
          <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="400"/>
          </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
          <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="18" />
            <RowDefinition Height="200" />
          </Grid.RowDefinitions>
          <TextBlock Text="{Binding FileName}" Style="{StaticResource ImageDescr}" />
          <Image Grid.Row="1" Source="{Binding Image}" Style="{StaticResource ImageTheme}" />
         </Grid>
       </DataTemplate>
     </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
  </ItemsControl>
```

Very neat.

Comment: try call `LoadImages()` in ViewModel1 constructor.

Comment: As a note, you should not be using the type BitmapImage in your view model. Instead, use the base class ImageSource, or if you really need to access bitmap-specific properties, use BitmapSource.

Comment: Besides that, what is the supposed magic behind the ContentChanged event? Is it ever subscribed to by any component? Shouldn't there be something like `OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Images))` instead.

Comment: @LeiYang Yes, this works, but only once during initialization. I clarified my question.

Comment: Also be aware that both UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged and Mode=TwoWay are pointless on a Source Binding of an Image element.

Comment: @Clemens:  Yeah, in the MainViewModel constructor : VM1.ContentChanged += (s, e) => OnPropertyChanged(); This is even called, but doesn't help with my issue.

Comment: There should be `OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Images))` instead of `OnContentChanged()` in the Images property setter. The OnPropertyChanged() call attached in the MainViewModel constructor is useless.

Comment: if you bind like "<Image Source="{Binding Images[0]}" "/>" I think there is no notification when "Images[0]" gets assigned.
If you bind like "<Image Source="{Binding Images} Path=[0]"/>" there is a notification, if Images is an observable collection

Comment: @Clemens Oh I confused the Source property of the Image control with the Source property of a Binding.
Anyhow if you want to get change notifications when you bind to an item of a collection, and the item is changed through the indexer, the collection must implement INotifyCollectionChanged and also you can use an odd syntax like "<Image DataContext="{Binding Path=Images}" Source="{Binding Path=[0]}" "/> to bind to image at index 0.
But my code was bit messy, I agree ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ContentChanged` event is useless.

Declare the `Images` property like this:

```
private ImageSource[] images;

public ImageSource[] Images
{
    get { return images; }
    set
    {
        images = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}
```

In `LoadImages()`, just assign a new array:

```
public void LoadImages()
{
    ...  
    Images = files
        .Select(f => Utility.BmImageFromFile(f))
        .ToArray();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display ***all* the images** of the `_images` collection of the current view model (which is the "current view") I would display them in a `ListBox` and put the image tag and the binding into the ListBox's `ItemTemplate`.

Also as previously mentioned by others, using an `ObservableCollecztion<ImageSource>` is strongly recommended since your collection data changes and you want your UI to notice it.

If you don't use an ObservableCollection, the view and images get only updated if the view model as a whole changes.

Comment: Better use an ItemsControl unless you also want to be able to select images.

Answer (score 0):

```cs
class RiJustageViewModel: ObservableObject
{
    public event EventHandler ContentChanged;
    void OnContentChanged()
    {
        ContentChanged?.Invoke(this, new EventArgs());
    }

    public RelayCommand LoadImagesCommand { get; set; }
    
    public ViewModel1()
    {
        // If this is not an observable collection,
        // then it makes no sense to create it in advance.
        // Images = new BitmapImage[9];

        LoadImagesCommand = new RelayCommand(o => LoadImages());
    }

    // Since it is not an observable collection,
    // the more general interface can be used: IEnumerable or IEnumerable <T>.
    IEnumerable<BitmapImage> _images;

    public IEnumerable<BitmapImage> Images
    {
        get { return _images; }
        set
        {
            _images = value;
            OnContentChanged();
        }
    }

    public void LoadImages()
    {  
        [...]
        // For an unobservable collection,
        // changing elements does not automatically change their presentation.
        // We need to create a NEW collection with
        // new elements and assign it to the property.
        BitmapImage[] localImages = new BitmapImage[files.Length];
        for (int i = 0; i < files.Length; i++)
        {
           localImages[i] = Utility.BmImageFromFile(files[i]);
        }
        Images = localImages;
        [...]
    }
}
```

This implementation has a drawback - it creates a new collection of images each time.
From memory, it doesn't matter (compared to other WPF costs).
But replacing a collection results in a re-creation of the UI elements that represent it.
And this is already significantly longer delays.
For your task, this is also not important, since this happens very rarely.

But for more loaded scenarios, it is better to use an observable collection (INotifyCollectionChanged) or a bindable list (IBindingList).
It is typical for WPF to use `ObservableCollection<T>`.

But in the case of asynchronous work with them, you need to take measures to work with it was thread-safe.
For the implementation I have shown, thread safety is not needed.
This is already implemented in the Binding mechanism itself to work with the INotifyPropertyChanged interface.

Comment: "*replacing a collection results in a re-creation of the UI elements that represent it*" would be true for an ItemsControl, but not here.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, together with Clemens answer it works without the ContentChanged event.

Comment: Another recommendation for implementing UserControl.
You explicitly specify several separate Image's in XAML with the binding of their source to the collection by the index of the elements.
In WPF, it is better to use ItemsControl in such cases.
In addition to simplifying the XAML code, you also additional get the automatic change in the number of displayed items.